# Select only links pointing to secure sites (https) to change color

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am trying different selectors using CSS. I am confused. I want to change  only the the links that is pointing to secure sites (https). I want to change the  color of secured links. How can I do that?
Here the code containing first two https and the rest one http:

```css
a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Selectors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="exercise.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[href^="https://"]`. Selects all a tags whose href begins with `https://`.

```css
a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px;
}
a[href^="https://"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Selectors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="exercise.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

More info about attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Unfortunately, some http links have port 443, which also forces HTTPS. It is not possible to style such links with CSS, but you might get some hope with JavaScript:

```js
// Get all links with href attribute
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  const link = links[i];
  const href = link.href;
  const split = href.replace("http://", "");
  const parts = split.split("/");
  if (parts[0].endsWith(":443")) {
    link.classList.add('red');
  }
}
```

```css
a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px;
}
a[href^="https://"] {
  color: red;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Selectors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="exercise.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com:443">Google</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is ^= in `a[href^="https://"]` ?

Comment: `^=` means `starts with`.